# How do I find when a class is used as service?

Tags: entities

I was searching for how to find field info and came across [getFieldDefinitions on Drupal 8 (why all these deprecated functions on DP8?)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203507/getfielddefinitions-on-drupal-8-why-all-these-deprecated-functions-on-dp8) which says to use `\Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions(xxx, xxx);`.

How can I tell from [`EntityFieldManager::getFieldDefinitions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/function/EntityFieldManager%3A%3AgetFieldDefinitions/8.2.x) that it needs to be called as a service, and that the service is entity_field.manager?

Why doesn't `\Drupal\EntityFieldManager::getFieldDefinitions($etid, $bundle)` work?

Answer (score 1):

From the page describing a method, you cannot know if the method is implemented from a service, but if you look at [the page describing the class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/class/EntityFieldManager/8.2.x), you will notice the class implements a service.

> [image: screenshot]

*1 service uses EntityFieldManager* doesn't mean *the code of a service uses EntityFieldManager*, but that `EntityFieldManager` is the class that defines a service. In this case, the machine name of the service is *entity_field.manager*, as given from the *entity_field.manager in core/core.services.yml* line.

As for the second question, that is plain PHP.   `\Drupal\EntityFieldManager::getFieldDefinitions($etid, $bundle)` means *call the `getFieldDefinitions()` static method of the `\Drupal\EntityFieldManager` class*. Since `\Drupal\EntityFieldManager::getFieldDefinitions()` is not a static method, you cannot call it like that, but you need an object, as in `$entity_file_manager->getFieldDefinition()`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I tell from EntityFieldManager::getFieldDefinitions() that it needs to be called as a service, and that the service is entity_field.manager?

The online docs are quite effective for this. For example, look at the [docs for the `EntityFieldManager` class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/class/EntityFieldManager/8.2.x), which contain an explicit reference:

> 1 service uses EntityFieldManager
>
> [entity_field.manager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/entity_field.manager/8.2.x) in [core/core.services.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/8.2.x)
>
> [Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFieldManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/class/EntityFieldManager/8.2.x)

> Why doesn't \Drupal\EntityFieldManager::getFieldDefinitions($etid, $bundle) work?

Because `getFieldDefinitions` is not a static method; you can't call it statically.